# What punctuation characters are necessary for a city field?

Tags: regex, street-address, punctuation, city

I'm considering a regex to restrict punctuation in city names (worldwide).  What would be a fairly inclusive whitelist of these?

I'm thinking:

```
 (space)
. period
- hyphen
' apostrophe
```

Also thinking maybe comma or slash but I don't have any examples. Are there others?

Comment: I think that's all of them..  with the exception of city names that contain special chars like: Hōnaunau, or San Josè, etc..  But most city databases and sites that I know of do not use any of those special chars and basically just strip out those chars and use the US alphabet equivalent, such sa Honaunau, or San Jose.

Comment: In the US, all city names (according to USPS and, I believe, the USCB) are stored as ASCII in official databases. In the world, you'd have to account for accent folding. (Maybe consider, instead of restricting input, to strip non-allowed punctuation instead... but in some languages, the accent characters do affect meaning and spelling.)

Comment: @Matt: you're right I think stripping is the better option. I'm mostly concerned with punctuation rather than letters as I plan to allow extended Latin characters

Comment: Just don't forget about Westward Ho! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Westward_Ho!

Comment: _"I'm considering a regex to restrict punctuation in city names (worldwide)"_ - **why?**

Comment: I'm with @PeterBoughton, why can't you just properly escape the input?

Comment: Please don't forget [Saint-Louis-du-Ha!-Ha!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint-Louis-du-Ha!_Ha!) :/

Comment: @PeterBoughton: I'm considering a whitelist of characters for a city field because I'm not sure I want to allow chinese/japanese/arabic characters in a city field (because I cannot read them).  Since I must specify allowed characters for this I also need specify punctuation.

Comment: @User And if you can't read its name, the city doesn't exist or doesn't have inhabitants?

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/general_punctuation/list.htm) is the most inclusive whitelist of punctuation to be found in city names.  The ASCII apostrophe codepoint may not be the one used when someone is entering an apostrophe on their keyboard.

If you've discerned the encoding of the submitted text, you should be able to see if it falls under the Punctuation block:

```
/\p{InGeneral_Punctuation}/
```

If you are limiting yourself to Latin-Extended, just use those:

```
/\p{InLatin_Extended-A}/
```

Also, ask yourself: What are the consequences of someone putting a funny character into my city name?  Is that worse than the consequences of someone not being able to enter their correct address, if I exclude too much?

Answer (score 2):

USPS standard address formatting calls for stripping all special characters except 'necessary' hyphens and dashes used in the primary and/or secondary street address lines and hyphens in the ZIP.

So if an address is:

```
John O'Toole
456 N 4-1/2 St
San José, CA 99999-4545
```

The post office prefers envelopes be labeled:

```
John O Toole
456 N 4 1/2 St
San Jose CA 9999-4545
```